# ARCore Unity change white balance (Android)

Tags: c#, android, unity-game-engine, shader, arcore

I am trying to adjust the white balance (color temperature) of the AR camera in one of the ARCore examples (AugmentedImage) in Unity3D.
Is there any way to change within the app the camera settings of the smartphone (Android) to a different fixed white balance?

I would prefer to adapt the camera view to match my objects white balance (~2800K) rather than changing the object to match the real scene. Although any solution is fine.

I have found the chapter "Choosing a specific camera config from the available configs" in the ARCore tutorial, but I did not really get any further understanding of that. (https://developers.google.com/ar/develop/unity/light-estimation)

Update: I found the ARBackground.shader file in the ARCore sample and I suppose there might be a chance to change something there, although my knowledge about shaders is limited.

Does somebody have any input for this problem of mine?
Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the included ARBackground.shader file in the ARCore sample I have altered the following lines, multiplying the color channels with different weights.
The resulting camera image is accurate enough for my purposes.

```
vec3 scalingVec = vec3(1.1f, 1.0f, 1.01f);
vec3 tmpVec = texture(_MainTex, textureCoord).rgb;
vec3 resVec = tmpVec * scalingVec;
mainTexColor = resVec;
```